# How to select an item from helm menu (spacemacs)?

Tags: spacemacs

RET works fine when I do `C-x C-f` to open the file. But it doesn't work when I do `M-x` and try to pick one of the items of helm menu. Would really appreciate you help.

Mac, fresh install of spacemacs.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Yes, it works for me now. It was some issue with spacemacs I believe.